# std::thread member object crashes on destruction in terminate

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I have a program where I want to run one of my classes in a separate thread with a higher priority than the rest of the program and I want it to update the GUI as it processes so I'm using `std::thread`.

**GUI.h**

```
#include <thread>

class GUI
{
private:
   Worker worker;

   std::thread workerThread;

public:
   GUI ();
   ~GUI ();

   void runWorker ();
}
```

**GUI.cpp**

```
GUI::GUI ()
{
}

GUI::~GUI()
{
}

void GUI::runWorker()
{
   workerThread = std::thread (&Worker::run, worker);
}
```

**Worker.h**

```
class Worker
{
public:
   void run ();
}
```

**Worker.cpp**

```
void Worker::run ()
{
   unsigned int numItems = 70;

   for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < numItems ; i++)
   {
      try
      {
         processItem (i);
      }
      catch (exception &e)
      {
         std::cout << "Error processing item " << i << std::endl;

         break;
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is whether `Worker::run` finishes cleanly or if there is an exception it will end and when I try to call the destructor for GUI it crashes in `std::terminate` in `std::thread`.

Is this a problem because the `std::thread` no longer exists because the Worker has already finished?  How can I keep the GUI destructor from calling the `std::thread` destructor if `Worker::run` has already finished?

Comment: It crashes because you never join the thread. [`std::thread::~thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) `If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::thread`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) will `std::terminate()` on destruction if it manages a thread.
Call `.join()` or `.detach()` for orderly ending, depending on what you need.

Alternatively upgrade to C++20, which introduced [`std::jthread`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/%7Ejthread) which joins instead of terminating.

Comment: I was under the impression that thread::join would block until the Worker finishes. I don't want it to block because i want the GUI to check active

Comment: So if I do a detach my worker will be "unmanaged" so the thread won't terminate?

Comment: yes, you got the difference between detaching and joining.